# velocity is not a function materialize showing error in meteor

Tags: meteor, materialize

```
materialize.js:3503 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).css(...).velocity is not a function
(anonymous function) @ materialize.js:3503
jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4665
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4333
```

error in console shows up when I click on card (materailize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Becuase you may be including another version on jquery in you head tag. When you install materailize with meteor it also adds jquery as its dependency. Both versions are conflicting with each other. All you need to do is exclude that jquery script tag in your head tag.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this is used the jquery version that is located in the materialize folder

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('materialize-css/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js');
require('materialize-css');
```

Answer (score -3):

The module **materialize** is incomplete.

I have created a solution for this problem, available on GitHub:

Create without webpack and velocity error : https://github.com/webpremium/angular2-materialize-cordova

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer and your solution doesn't help other readers.